# Cosa significa "di risvolto" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Rinascimento privato* di Maria Bellonci ho letto:

> Mi interrogai. Dov'era il dolore? Taceva. Solo l'ira e la pietà mi nutrivano nelle più remote fibre. Sarei vissuta d'ira e di pietà, dunque? Naufragavo. Ma tornando a respirare assunsi una ringagliardita avidità di agire come se ogni frecciata mi suscitasse una istigazione. A goccia a goccia mi riavevo, mi sembrava che qualcuno disegnasse per me su una mappa segreta i miei piani. E conoscevo il mio bersaglio. C'era a Milano uno da
>   conquistare, il personaggio che in quel momento sovrabbondava in potenza, il Viceré Raimondo di Cardona, sempre più preso d'amore per la mia Brognina e così cavalleresco da permettere al suo sentimento di primeggiare su tutte le sue azioni. Comandava l'esercito che doveva muovere all'assalto di Ferrara, era lui dunque l'uomo da soggiogare: se ci fosse riuscita l'impresa, Eros avrebbe vinto su Marte.
>
> **Di risvolto**, inanimita, mi spesi in preparativi a momenti rabbiosi: le stanze si trasformarono in tavolozze di colori commentati dalle guarnizioni dorate e inargentate e rilevati da trine e ricami.

Ho cercato il significato di "risvolto" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il senso dell'espressione "di risvolto" nel passaggio precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Bisognerebbe conoscere anche le frasi precedenti, ma credo voglia significare "per contro" o "per reazione" a quello che è successo in precedenza.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Riporto il paragrafo precedente.

Comment: Il significato è quello di "per contro" https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/per-contro

Comment: Leggendo meglio il paragrafo riportato, confermo che secondo me ha un significato simile a "per reazione" o "di conseguenza"